# how to get value of inner <span> ,which does not have id or class slectors except parent div value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on customization of a wordpress theme ,there was a situation that,When ever user resizes the browser window text content on the page should change its color.I successfully done with this using javascript in some standalone html page .Coming to the wordpress theme,I posted the code of the  block from which i want to get the text and changes its color dynamically on resize below this post.The thing is that inner span and

elements of the following  with class name "wpb_wrapper"did not have either ,'id' or 'class' selector.Without selector my function is not identifying the inner html elements and i'm not getting the values.I even tried some of the following things:

1. Firefox Xpath finder. (JS not rendering it!!)
2. `document.select("span.wp_wrapper").get(0).nextElementSibling().text();`
3. `document.getElementById("item1").nextElementSibling.innerHTML`

Theme Original Code:

```html
|<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span><p></p>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span>
  </p></div>
```

Comment: Do  you mean there is actual inline CSS?

Comment: Why dont you just: `$('.wpb_wrapper').css({'color': 'red'});`?

Comment: Not sure why you have a problem. `$('.wpb_wrapper span')` will access the spans.

Comment: use media queries? .wpb_wrapper span {color:red !important} for the resolutions you like

Comment: `.wpb_wrapper span{ color:green !important;}` use this.

Answer (score 1):

Might be you want to change all span text color in `wpb_wrapper` class then you have to write following selector.

```
$('.wpb_wrapper span').css({'color': 'red'});
```

```js
$('.wpb_wrapper span').css({'color': 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span><p></p>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">Some Text</span>
  </p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the following CSS:

using `!important`

in order to override the inline CSS property present in your HTML (`style="color: #000000;"`).

This approach use pure CSS and JS is not required.

```
.wpb_wrapper span   {color:green !important}
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8hxatjah/

More info on CSS on `!important` [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie edit with example http://jsfiddle.net/8hxatjah/ ..yes you can using !important

Comment: Indeed. Comment removed :)

Comment: Please explain why the OP should consider using `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

In Jquery

```
$('.wpb_wrapper span').css({'color': 'red'});
```

In css

```
.wpb_wrapper span   {color:red !important}
```

Comment: `!important` is not required for the inline styling (unless you want it to be *really* important) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access a child of an HTML element by using

```
$('.wpb_wrapper span')
```

Or if you're working on a responsive layout, you can use the

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   .wpb_wrapper span { color: #000000;}
}
```

Comment: Look for duplicate answers before posting. Also your comment is incorrect as your example is a *descendant* selector (not *child*).

Comment: Your media query is changing the background color and not foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!! And Finally this was done using Jquery

```html
$('.wpb_wrapper span').css({'color': 'red'});
```

Thanks Every One!! But how could this can done using JavaScript .. Any way Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

1. `$('.wpb_wrapper').find('span').text()` you can use to get the value of span for one span value.
2. As you Have multiple span elements inside the div.
   if you want to get the each span value use the below code

   $('.wpb_wrapper').find('span').each(function(){
   $(this).text();
   });
3. If you want only one span value out of multiple spans, Please add id for each span element.

Comment: The question is about changing color styling on the spans, not getting the text values. This has nothing to do with the question asked.